# How to connect to AWS Elasticsearch service using access key in PHP?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-sdk

I am having Access key and Secret key for elasticsearch domain. Please help to connect to ES domain for indexing data.

Is there any SDK from AWS for Elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0):

You need to sign your request when accessing the service. Here are some documentation links explaining this I've received in a support request I opened for the exact same issue - 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/service/es-data-plane.html

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signing_aws_api_requests.html

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html

Or you can either use reverse proxy - 
https://eladnava.com/secure-aws-elasticsearch-service-behind-vpc/

Answer (score 0):

I did it by using the following link.

https://github.com/wizacha/AwsSignatureMiddleware

Its working fine.